# How to write a currency value (and format it as currency) with currency different than dollars? (!)

Tags: google-sheets

In a Google Sheets if I write in a cell "€30" or "€ 30" or "30€" or "30 €" and then I set it as currency, it always becomes "$30.00".

Why does it become in dollars?

Comment: This looks like a question for http://superuser.com/

Comment: I forgot to add that I offer an one-million-euros prize for the answer to this.  But it will be automatically reduced to one-million-dollars as soon as you press the button "Post Your Answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can highlight the cells that you want and click the "123" icon on the toolbar. Then you can choose "More Currencies" and select the currency that you want.